# trouble flipping CoreGraphics upside down arc in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am having trouble flipping an arc using core graphics api in a UIView.

I understand that the coordinate system is different. UIkit helps me half way by transforming the coordinate system to accommodate the center I provide into a core graphic coordination system. I am assuming that when I draw an arc using core graphics api that its drawing the arc by using the core graphics coordinate system?

I can just change clockwise to false and it will give me what I need. Is this good practice?

I was playing around with CGAffineTransform’s rotation and scale, it didn’t give me what I need. Any way to flip the arc around without hawkishly changing clocking to false?

I also used UIBezierPath to draw another arc the way I want it. As I understand, UIBezierPath is a wrapper around CoreGraphics. I would like to know how I can do this using pure CoreGraphics API.

Extra question: My last function
Call `path.stroke()` paints the UIBezierPath path and the CGPath arcPath1. How come? 0.o

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    let boxPath = CGMutablePath()

    boxPath.addLines(between:
    [CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height),
     CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2),
     CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height / 2)])

    CGContext.beginPath() // begin new path
    CGContext.addPath(boxPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: 5.0, lineCap: .square, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 0)) // add new path

    CGContext.setFillColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
    CGContext.fillPath()

    let arcPath1 = CGMutablePath()
    arcPath1.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 4, y: rect.height / 4 * 3),
                    radius: 20.0,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(180).degreesToRadians,
                    endAngle: CGFloat(360).degreesToRadians,
                    clockwise: true,
                    transform: CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(0).degreesToRadians))


    CGContext.beginPath()
    CGContext.addPath(arcPath1)
    CGContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)

    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 4 * 3, y: rect.height / 4 * 3),
                            radius: 20.0,
                            startAngle: CGFloat(180).degreesToRadians,
                            endAngle: CGFloat(360).degreesToRadians,
                            clockwise: true)

    path.lineWidth = 5.0
    path.stroke()
}
```

[Arcs, left: CG, right: Bezier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tJTt.png)

Comment: This is a bug/feature that has existed since the first iPhone SDK.  On macOS, the lower-right corner is (0, 0), but when they flipped the coordinate system on the iPhone, they didn't consider that clockwise would switch to counter-clockwise.  Setting the clockwise variable "backwards" is the simplest (and therefore, probably the best) solution.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks man.

Comment: Ugh, typo.  On macOS, (0, 0) is lower-left.  The flip for iOS is vertical.